# Plugin for showing single product on a page

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm sure that I'm not the first person who wondered if it's possible and there already should be a whole bunch of such plugins but I cannot find any of them.

So, the task is to show only one product on a page. For instance, I create a post and I want to insert one particular (or random with some criteria) product from WP or Woo on this page. Something with a shortcode, I guess, like `[product id=123]`

Of course, I can extend `functions.php` but maybe there is a plugin with more options and customization. Like using a custom layout, showing several products and so on.

Comment: Hi have you seen the Products shortcodes explained in the docs here? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: @NathanielFlick, no, I have not. But it seems like what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad i could help.